# Invalid viewstate when using RewritePath

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-rewriting, viewstate

I have this in my global.asax

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string pathAndQuery = Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToString().ToLower();
    if (pathAndQuery.Contains("prettyUrl"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("Category.aspx?catg=uglyUrl");
    }
}
```

it works fine, but I sometimes get this **500 unable to validate data**
so i guess that is because the checksum is generated on behalf of the url. which does not match the viewstate.

So how do you solve it so that you can use `RewritePath` but don't get the 500 errors?

**Edit** forgot to mention that i have a static machinekey validationkey in the web.config

**Edit2** found someone else has exactly the same problem: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/298680-form-action-context-rewritepath#post1172026

the rewritepath causes an invalid viewstate when there is a postback

Comment: Did you have a question you'd like to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching from to maproutes from `System.Web.Routing`

**Old code:**

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string pathAndQuery = Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToString().ToLower();

    if (pathAndQuery.Contains("thisisawesome"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("Products.aspx?catg=14&cat=161");
    }
}
```

**New code:**

source: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("test", 
                        "thisisawesome", 
                        "~/Products.aspx?catg=14&cat=161");
}
```